# How can I write a dictionary within another dictionary to a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary within a dictionary like below:

```
{'ID1':{'sam':1,'maj':5, 'tif':7, 'paul':1},
 'ID2':{'maj':4,'bib':5},
 ...}
```

How do I write this to a CSV file? I would like to have a separate cumulus for main keys and separate columns for inner keys

Comment: And what information would you expect to find in the CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]I suppose this is what you are looking for:

```
import csv
with open('/home/test/kelvin1/add.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    kev = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                 quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    k ={'ID1':{'sam':1,'maj':5,'tif':7,'paul':1},'ID2':{'maj':4,'bib':5}}
    for i in k:
          kev.writerow(i)
          for j in k[i]:
              kev.writerow(j)
              kev.writerow('%d' % (k[i][j]))
```

This code is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Hope this points you in the right direction. Assuming you want to go in sorted order of IDs.

```
>> import csv
>>> d = {'ID1':{'sam':1,'maj':5, 'tif':7, 'paul':1},'ID2':{'maj':4,'bib':5},}
>>> with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
        fieldnames = ('sam', 'maj', 'tif', 'paul', 'bib')
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames)
        for k, row in sorted(d.items()):
            w.writerow(row)


>>> with open('test.csv') as f: # showing contents
        print f.read()


1,5,7,1,    
,4,,,5
```